# Angular ng if array[0] = 'Value' don't work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like that my icon would only be visible if my array[0] = 'Value' :

**HTML**

```
<ion-icon *ngIf="allFamily[0] = 'Value'" class="checkas" name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
```

**TS**

```
allFamily = [
    {0: 'Value'}
]
```

But this isn't working, it shows ion-icon all the time.
Note that 0: 'Value' I am adding after ion-icon shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `==` for comparison not `=`

```
<ion-icon *ngIf="allFamily[0] == 'Value'" class="checkas" name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: so which one is trully == or === ? because I've got two different answers.

Comment: `===` is type secured while comparison

Comment: @Angulandy2 This might help explain the difference between `==` and `===`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons.

Comment: Both works, but it's a good habit to use `===` whenever possible, because that's what you usually want and it gives you additional security.

Answer (score 1):

You need **`===`** to check equality **`=`** is for assignment,

```
<ion-icon *ngIf="allFamily[0] ==='Value'" class="checkas" name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
```